# How can I use Stanford's NER against Spanish language text?

Tags: stanford-nlp

How can I use Stanford's NER against Spanish language text?

I have successfully downloaded Stanford's NER system, and I have been able to extract named entities with the following sort of command:

```
#!/bin/sh
scriptdir=`dirname $0`
java -mx700m -cp "$scriptdir/stanford-ner.jar:$scriptdir/lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier $scriptdir/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile $1
```

But I am really trying to process Spanish language texts. I see that some sort of Spanish language jar file is available (stanford-spanish-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar). Unfortunately, I don't know how to use it with the given NER system.

How can I use the Stanford NER system against Spanish language data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties -file sample-text.txt -outputFormat text
```

You need to make sure you have the spanish models jar in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but for me, the solution above is like one step forward and half a step back. Using the command above I have been able to more accurately identify the named entities in a Spanish language text, but the resulting (XML) output is not quite as useful as the inlineXML output of the NER-only solution. From the command line, is there someway to get StanfordCoreNLP to output inline XML, or alternatively, is there some way to get the NER-only command-line tool to use the Spanish language model?